# unable to start postgres server after changing into pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf to connect with all user using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql

This is the error i am getting when i install the postgresql on ubantu machine. then on that machine i can connect it successfully but as soon as i changed into below files to allow all the user to connect with it .then i noticed it won't start

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
            Is the server running locally and accepting
            connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

```
BELOW you can see my pg_hba.conf
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                    peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                    md5

ghost    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

BELOW  you can see postgresql.conf

```
# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'          # use data in another directory
                                        # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf'        # host-based authentication file
                                        # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_ident.conf'    # ident configuration file
                                        # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid'                   # write an extra PID file
                                        # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authenticatio
```

n -`

Comment: The log file will tell you.

Comment: I have reinstalled postgres and changed into above two files to all allow users but still not able to connect to pgAdmin  .can you please help me out

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7020/postgres
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "xx.xx.xx.xx" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?  but on localhost on ubantu i can connect with psql .

Comment: Use `netstat -anp | grep postgres` to see if it actually is listening on 0.0.0.0:5432, if yes then check firewall `ufw status verbose`

Comment: thank you for your reply however i haved checked its lisiting on same port but and i have disable the firewall also . Eelike   .  still not able figured out whats wrong with it ?